# Evernote read-only notes using contentClass

Tags: python, api, readonly, evernote

I am trying to make notes in a notebook read only by using the contentClass attribute.

My code is below:

I can set other attributes, but as soon as I try and set the contentClass, it throws an EDAM exception on create note. (Company and app name has been changed)

```
attrib = Types.NoteAttributes()
attrib.sourceApplication = 'Company_evernoteApp'
attrib.source = 'Company'
attrib.contentClass = 'Company.App'
new_note.attributes = attrib
```

This is throwing the error:

```
evernote.edam.error.ttypes.EDAMUserException: EDAMUserException(errorCode=2, parameter='NoteAttributes.contentClass')
```

later on in the code when I try and call:

```
new_note = note_store.createNote(new_note)
```

Am I using contentClass right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage seems to be fine.
The errorCode=2 means the format of the contentClass is wrong.

The regex it has to follow is [here](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Limits.html#Const_EDAM_NOTE_CONTENT_CLASS_REGEX).